# How to list all producers of a kafka cluster?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am able to list all Kafka Consumer with `KafkaAdminClient`:

```
AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(conf);
ListTopicsResult ltr = client.listTopics();
KafkaFuture<Set<String>> names = ltr.names();

ArrayList<ConsumerGroupListing> consumerGroups = new ArrayList<>(client.listConsumerGroups().all().get());
ConsumerGroupListing consumerGroup = consumerGroups.get(0);
```

Is it possible to list all registrated producers in a similar way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In contrast to consumers, it is **not** possible to retrieve such information since Kafka brokers don't store any kind of information about the producers connected to them.

Comment: Have you got a reference for this?

Comment: This is not true as the producers will be registered upon the first write and their ids expire by default 7 days after the last write. See https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#brokerconfigs_transactional.id.expiration.ms.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get all active producer using AdminClient API:

```java
Collection<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = ...

DescribeProducersResult result = adminClient.describeProducers(
  Collections.singleton(topicPartition)
);

Map<TopicPartition, DescribeProducersResult.PartitionProducerState> producerStateMap = result.all().get();
```

https://kafka.apache.org/32/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/KafkaAdminClient.html#describeProducers(java.util.Collection,org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.DescribeProducersOptions)